# Should {list-of-figures} be merged with {table-of-content}?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Should the tags [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents), [list-of-figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-of-figures) and [list-of-tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-of-tables) be merged? After all, their implementations are pretty similar and questions and solutions applying to one of them typically apply to the others as well.

Comment: Wouldn't just a tag synonym work?

Comment: @Hendrik: I guess Caramdir meant creating synonyms and merging afterwards.

Comment: @Stefan: What I meant: Doesn't it suffice to create synonyms? (But maybe I don't know what I'm talking about; I'm not even exactly sure what a tag synonym is.)

Comment: @Hendrik: without merging, 6 resp. 2 questions for the tag synonyms would remain, future questions would be automatically retagged. In contrast, merging tidies it up and moves all questions the target tag, leaving pure synomyms.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, now I understand. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Actually I meant creating synonyms. Does the remapping stay in effect after merging. I don't know if everyone who asks about lists of figures will find the table-of-contents tag if there aren't synonyms.

Comment: @Caramdir: The remapping does stay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that would be ok. Even somebody browsing old list-of-figures questions could benefit from the other questions and answers regarding the table of contents.

Though being able to distinguish different concepts is important, TOC, LOF and LOT aren't really different.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, too.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be confusing for casual users of the site.  That the implementation is similar is less visible than the difference in semantics.

I don't really see who would benefit from this synonym.  People with a special expertise in these macros looking for questions to answer?  People wanting to earn tag badges?

Comment: in the long run, synonyms reduce tag badges. But they can help to keep the site tidied up.

Comment: The main advantage is that questions and answers should be easier to find. Now solutions to similar problems are distributed over several tags (tags are my main aid when searching for duplicates if I remember that a similar question has been asked before). Further, there are some questions about List of Something (for Something not tables or figures) and in the current setting there is no suitable tag for them.

Comment: Also the {list-of-figures} and {list-of-tables} tags are still available for question askers (they are just remapped to {table-of-contents}, so that there shouldn't be any confusion there.

Comment: @Caramdir: The issue is that when one visits, say [tag:string], it is not surprising that one lands on a page with no mention of the string tag, but only a different tag, strings.  This redirect is different: it may surprise some people in certain situations.  I'd call it an expert's tag.