# Two small tag merging suggestions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

A while ago, the former tags [list-of-figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-of-figures) and [list-of-tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-of-tables) were merged with [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) (and kept as synomyms). Caramdir's [reasoning](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/854/should-list-of-figures-be-merged-with-table-of-content) for this was that *"their implementations are pretty similar and questions and solutions applying to one of them typically apply to the others as well"*.

In the same spirit, I'd like to discuss two potential merging/synonym measures:

- [maketitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maketitle) and [titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titlepage) could be combined into a new [titling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titling) tag. (In this case, I'm not so sure if solutions are overlapping to a great extend.)
- [widows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widows) and [orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orphans) should be combined into [widows-orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widows-orphans). (The TeXniques for controlling widows and orphans are the same, or at least for the most part if you consider tinkering with `\Needspace` as a separate way to control orphans.)

EDIT: I ask a moderator to implement these merging/synonym suggestions. The new tag names should be [titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) (as suggested by Aditya) and [widows-orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widows-orphans).

Comment: To me, titling has a different connotation that titlepage or maketitle. Titling means giving a title to a work. Perhaps, `{titles}` might be a better tag.

Comment: How about {titlepages} as the main tag? It would be conceptual and consistent with our plural tags.

Comment: @Stefan: Titles aren't always typeset on their own page (e.g. by default in the `article` class), so I prefer {titles}.

Comment: done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [titling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titling)

This would be in line with our preferance of concept tags over command tags. [maketitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maketitle) might automatically involve further commands such as `\title` and `\author`. Often `\maketitle` is the cause of a question but a `titlepage` the solution. So I agree with merging into the concept tag [titling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titling).

### [widows-orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widows-orphans)

Sounds reasonable for me too. [widows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widows) and [orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orphans) are very often treated together, both in books and in questions. For instance, all but one [widows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widows) questions deal with [orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orphans) too.

I agree with keeping the current tags as synonyms, otherwise I would expect them to reappear soon.